# How to properly let the php pull data from the SQL database and loop through it

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I have a problem with looping through the pulled info form my database (MySQL)

I want to pull all the ID from the Forum table, like this:

```
SELECT ID FROM Forums
```

then loop through all the ID's and run

```
SELECT ID FROM Catagory WHERE Forum_ID = ?
```

This is the same in proper php:

```
$profile=$db->prepare('SELECT ID FROM Forums ');
$profile->execute();
$forums = $profile->fetch();

foreach ($forums as &$forum_ID) {

    // some code

    $profile=$db->prepare('SELECT ID FROM Catagories WHERE Forum_ID = ?');
    $profile->bindValue(1, $forum_ID);
    $profile->execute();
    $catagories = $profile->fetch();

    foreach ($categories as &$category_ID ) {

        //some more of my code
    }
}
```

With this code i get an error:

```
Undefined variable: categories
```

Please do not mind the spelling errors they are spelled that way in my database, im dyslectic

Thanks in advance

EDIT: For this test i made sure there is something to return by the SQL server

Comment: $catagories !== $categories ---- A !== E

Comment: Like Mark said, you have typo in the code. you assign the results of fetch to $catAgories, but in loop, you use $catEgories

Comment: @MarkBaker nice eyes! catagories and categories

Comment: Mark is right. If you want to be consistent in the typo's you should use `foreach ($catagories as &$category_ID ) {` rather than `$categories`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't mind the spelling errors. But PHP minds,

change `$catagories` into `$categories`.

Answer (score 0):

make change :

```
$catagories = $profile->fetch();
```

TO

```
$categories = $profile->fetch();
```

There is a spelling mistake.

Comment: Hadn't the same answer [Repeated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14520182/how-to-properly-let-the-php-pull-data-from-the-sql-database-and-loop-through-it/14520236#14520236)

Answer (score 0):

Your spelling errors are causing you some problems here. :)

You have:

```
$catagories = $profile->fetch();

foreach ($categories as &$category_ID ) {

    //some more of my code
}
```

So you assign the value from `fetch()` to `$catagories` but one line below you use `$categories`.

So change it to:

```
$categories = $profile->fetch();

foreach ($categories as &$category_ID ) {

    //some more of my code
}
```